# How mention the user roles?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm making a userinfo commands and i would like to mention the roles that the user have in the guild
Now i'm using this code:

```
embed.add_field(name='Roles:',
                value=f'{user.roles}',
                inline=True)
```

However trey return useless things
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOyI2.png)

Comment: Object role has a mention attribute   (role.mention) https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Role.mention

Comment: like this (user.roles).mention?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, which mentions them all in a single line when you run the command `!role_mentions @username`

```py
@commands.command()
async def role_mentions(self, ctx, member: discord.Member):
    roles = [role.mention for role in member.roles]
    embed = discord.Embed()
    embed.add_field(name='Roles:',
        value=f"{' '.join(roles)}",
        inline=True)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Or you can do something a role per field if you prefer them to vertical.

```py
@commands.command()
async def role_mentions(self, ctx, member: discord.Member):
    embed = discord.Embed()
    for role in member.roles:
        embed.add_field(name='\u200B:',
            value=role.mention,
            inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

\u200B is zero width character

Comment: A discord embed can only have 25 fields iirc, something to keep in mind for the second option

Comment: And 6000 limit size on all embeds, will many people have over 25 roles in a single discord?

Comment: In the discord my bot is in, some people have well over 30 roles. It's just a concern for some people maybe. 6000 characters will hold 260 role mentions so that would be less of a concern ;)

Answer (score 0):

after more search i found one way, here is it:

```
roles = " ".join([role.mention for role in user.roles if role.name != "@everyone"])
```

thanks for the help in comments